# How do I find and replace all occurrences (in all files) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out how to find and replace all occurrences of a word in different files using Visual Studio Code version 1.0.

I get the impression this should be possible since doing Ctrl + Shift + F allows me to simply search a folder, but i am clueless to how to proceed from here.

I looked in various key combination
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings

But I only found how to replace all occurrences in the open file (Ctrl + h)

All help gratefully appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: In all notes here the simple text "replace in files" doesn't disambiguate between open and closed files. In the current VSCode when you open the Find-All/Replace-All view there is a book icon for "Search only in open editors". Note also that your "files to include" and "files to exclude" _must_ be crafted carefully. Another icon there is "Use exclude settings and ignore files". When active you may not see everything you want - or you may see files you don't want. Finally, note the Refresh icon at the top, which may be required after changing other settings here. HTH

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Since version 1.3 of vscode this is **possible**

1. Navigate to the search, click icon to the left or:

   - (mac) `cmd + shift + h`
   - (PC) `ctrl + shift + h`
2. expand replace
3. enter search term and replace term
4. confirm!

[image: Search and replace with vscode]

Comment: To search stuff in a specific folder just add the folder path in the field `files to include`. You can find/replace stuff even outside the workspace. ⚠ it doesn't search within file names, but within the files. (Anyone knows how to search file name outside the workspace?)

Comment: 2021 its still not implemented, there is no button to click "replace-all" you need to use a keyboard shortcut... I guess I shouldn't completely replace sublime-text

Comment: @ta32 See gif for ux search and replace

Comment: Oh I see it now its a small button on the right with "ab"

Answer (score 786):

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.8, and this feature is available. But it's a little tricky to understand at first, and (at the time of writing) the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files) don't explain clearly how to use it, so here's how it works, step by step:

Invoke **Replace in Files** (under the Edit menu, or with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

You'll see a standard Find/Replace input replacing the files pane on the left:

[image]

Enter your search string and the replace string, then press enter. It may churn for a second searching all files, then it'll show the proposed changes in all your project files -- but note, these changes **haven't been made yet!** Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Now you need to **make the changes** (and even after that, you have to **save the modified files**.)

You can make those changes in various ways:

1. Make all changes to all files at once.

---

Click the replace icon next to your replace string *(note: you'll get a dialog to confirm this bulk action.)*

[image]

2. Make all changes in a single file at once.

---

Click the replace icon next to the filename *(note: the icon only shows up when you hover over the filename row)*

[image]

3. Make a single change in a single file.

---

Click the replace icon next to the individual change: *(note: the icon only shows up when you hover over the change row)*

[image]

## Finally, don't forget to save!

All those files are now modified in the editor and not yet saved to disk (unless Auto Save is on).

Use File -> Save All (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

**Update:** I'm not sure when this was added, but if you click the "Replace all" button and see this dialog, clicking "Replace" will change and save all files in one click:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to save a 'search-replace'? I often search for 'class=' and replace with 'className='

Comment: Is it possible to skip the last step and do a silent search and replace? If I'm doing a trivial search and replace, I don't want to save each individual file.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to either of these questions. But @satJ, note that `Ctrl+Alt+S` saves all modified files at once, so it's pretty quick and easy.

Comment: God damn that's dangerous, changing all files as default. Is there a command to just find/replace in a single file?

Comment: The current save all default is Ctrl-k, followed by the letter s. Ctrl-k, followed by Ctrl+w will close all your windows after the programs has opened a bunch of them.

Comment: In VS Code 1.31.1 (and possibly earlier) you can exclude files or lines of code from your find & replace operation by clicking the "close" icons in the file search results before you click replace.

Comment: I would prefer not to click the actual change, but while standing on a replace result line (a candidate for replacing) to have a shortcut to accept it and a shortcut for declining it. Do these exist? I looked for it but can not find any...

Comment: @musicformellons - maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but it would appear that you can navigate the "proposed changes" pane with the arrow keys, and use `del` to reject a change, or `ctrl-shift-1` to accept a change. A little cumbersome, but perhaps usable.

Comment: @JeffWard That's nice, thank you! Maybe you also know the shortcut to get from the search/ replace box to the "proposed changes"?

Comment: @musicformellons you can do it all via the keyboard: `ctrl-shift-h`, type search string, `tab`, type replace string, `enter` performs the search,`tab` about seven times to highlight the proposed changes pane, `down arrow` starts moving through proposed items.

Answer (score 58):

To replace a string in a single file (currently opened): <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd>

For replacing at workspace level use: <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + H</kbd>

Comment: Note: You have to press enter for the search to run when using Ctrl+Shift+H.

Answer (score 40):

**Update for 2020**

If you are using the search feature to search across files (`Ctrl + Shift + F`) it can be easy to miss how to convert your search to a search and replace within the UI.

Here's a typical search result:

> [image: search result image]

To convert this to a search and replace you need to click the arrow icon to the **left** of the search input field. This will open the replace options as seen below. Note the arrow icon is now pointed down.

> [image: search and replace image]

The keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + H` will also work as well to access the search and replace.

Link to VSCode docs on search and replace: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace

Comment: The general issue right now is, that after 10000 results, VSCode stops searching. Any workarounds for that? I.e. iterative search + replace addon?

Answer (score 31):

**This is the best way.**

1. First put your cursor on the member and click F2.
2. Then type the new name and hit the Enter key. This will rename all of the occurrences in every file in your project.

This is ideal for when you want to rename across multiple files. For example, you may want to rename a publicly accessible function on an Angular service and have everywhere that uses it get updated.

For more great tools I highly recommend:
https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/

Comment: what if i want to rename occurrences in only current file?

Comment: @temirbek i have been following this request for a while. It's been 2+ years and it hasn't been implemented yet. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14836

Comment: Hi, does it also rename the related folders and import?

Answer (score 10):

## Step by step with images

Nowadays in VS Code this can be done quickly.

**1)** Click on the **Search Button** (in the side bar):

[image]

**2)** Enter in the inputs what do you want to **find**, and with what do you want to **replace** it:

[image]

(Here I am replacing in my project all the occurrences of `table-cell` with `t-cell`)

**3)** Finally, click on this small button (Replace All):

[image]

Then a pop-up will appear to confirm if you want to replace all occurrences. Click on **Replace**.

And you're done!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

On the [Visual Studio Code Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) page, the section [Keyboard Shortcuts Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference) has links to a PDF for each major OS. Once open, search for "replace in files" or any other shortcut you might need.

Another way is to use the **Command Palette** (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) where you can type "replace" to list all related commands, including the one you want:

> Replace in Files <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio Code: Version: 1.53.2

---

If you are looking for the answer in 2021 (like I was), the answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/replace-in-files?view=vs-2019#to-display-replace-in-files) on the Microsoft website but honestly hard to follow.

Go to **Edit** > **Replace in Files**

[image]

From there it is similar to the search funtionality for a single file.

I changed the name of a class I was using across files and this worked perfectly.

*Note: If you cannot find the Replace in Files option, first click on the Search icon (magnifying glass) and then it will appear.*

Answer (score 5):

ctrl+shift+f (search box appear in left side type your word in the search box to replace)
ctrl+shift+h (type the word to replace with)
select replaceAll /replace accordingly TO REPLACE.

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 methods technically same**

1. First put your cursor on the word and press F2.
   Replace your word and press Enter.
2. First put your cursor on the word and left click it.
   Click "Rename Symbol" option.
   Replace your word and press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

In the VSC version 1.57
you can use the **F2 key** to replace on the folder(Rename Symbol)

Only thing is that even though all the places inside folder are replaced the file is not saved and the save has to be done afterwards

Also, instead of presing enter and replace all directly, you can press **Shift + Enter** to preview the places that are going to be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

For search and replace all use this command:
**command + option + F**

[image]

Comment: The above looks a lot like Sublime Text and not VS Code...

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

1. Select the keyword u need to replace:
2. Right click on it -> Select "Rename Symbol"

3. Type in the new name in text-box.