# Move a package to another package and also update string references?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, package, move

I'm using Eclipse IDE and i have following file structure:

```
/app
/res
/res/assets
/res/views/FXML/...(fxml files)
.....
```

I want to move the `/res` package to the package `/app`.

There is a `Move...` button in the `Refactor` context menu but it doesn't allow me to move a package to another one in the same project. Eclipse provides a feature to rename a package and also update the string paths. People were suggesting to rename the package too in the answers of other similar questions. But the problem i faced is a bit different:
I tried to rename the package `res` to `app.res` as Eclipse uses dot (`.`) as a path separator. But when eclipse updates a string path it uses dot(`.`) again. For example:
before: `String view_file = "/res/views/FXML/BaseUI.fxml";`
after updating: `String view_file = "/app.res/views/FXML/BaseUI.fxml";`
what i need: `String view_file = "/app/res/views/FXML/BaseUI.fxml";`

and dot(`.`) is not valid for paths. I also tried using `/` instead of dot(`.`) but didn't work. Well i could change the path manually but there are a lot of paths to update so it'll be time consuming.

So how can i accomplish this?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to replace all the paths using editors like VS Code, Sublime etc after moving the package manually.

In your case, the process would be like this, using VS Code:

1. Move the package `/res` to `/app` manually
2. Now open the project folder with VS Code
3. Go to `Search` sidebar
4. Search for `/res/views/FXML/BaseUI.fxml`
5. Enter `/app/res/views/FXML/BaseUI.fxml` in the `Replace` input box
6. Click on the `Replace All` button

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346481/how-do-i-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code) might be helpful for the replacing task.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

The solution I can provide, I must say frankly, is not the best but it will work if you do it right. So just make the new subfolder and copy all files to `app.res`, the new subfolder. So eclipse folder structore manager I think is not the best so I do it with my way. Yes, it is a bit complicated but it works.

Comment: manipulating folders doesn't update the string references to the resources. As far as i know, eclipse only updates references when you REFACTOR them as packages and stuff.