# How can I do "find and replace" inside a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

In my GitHub repository, I have many files and I have to change one of the words to another one. The problem is that, as the occurrences of that word is more than 200, I cannot change it one by one manually. Is there any way to facilitate this?

Comment: It seems strange that you need to update 200 files to change one word. You would almost certainly benefit from referencing a *single* file in this case with either an `include` or ` partial`. Then you would only need to update the one file, with the changes reflected in each of the 200 files.

Comment: The question title could be improved to include the fact that you're wanting to replace all instances across multiple files, in which case, we're looking at a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346481/how-do-i-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code) - although I realise that you were looking for a git-specific solution (which, from the answers below, appears to not exist).

Answer (score 5):

In edit mode, press `Ctrl + Shift + F`, the editor will ask you: `Replace`, type the search word, then press `Enter`, the editor will ask you: `With:`, type the replacement word and press `Enter`. Then follow the menu.

Comment: Do you know if there are keys set for "Yes", "No", "All", "Stop" as well?

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub code editor appears to only allow for [find and replace](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/keyboard-shortcuts#source-code-editing) on one file at a time.

You would likely benefit greatly from the use of a code editor like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) which supports [find and replace across all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346481/how-do-i-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code) in a project.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possibly to find-replace within a single file in the GitHub browser editor.

On Windows, the shortcut is `Ctrl + Shift + F`. On macOS, the shortcut is `Command + Opt + f`.