# Change replace and exclude multiline html code

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++

Looking for a bit of help.
After completing hundreds of pages, I came across an HTML error.
Need simply to move the /h1> closing tag to reside before the p> tag
Is it possible with notepad++ or other, to find these 6 lines and replace the /h1> tag from line 6 to the end of the second line?
Appreciate the help, if it's possible, as it will save a lot of work replacing it individually on all my pages.

Code is; tab delimited.

**Note: The title and paragraph are never the same.**

Find:

```
 <h1 id="h-title">
              Estatus rogue
              <p>ext 098 float
                <br>
              </p>
            </h1>
```

Replace with:

```
<h1 id="h-title">
              Estatus rogue</h1>
              <p>ext 098 float
                <br>
              </p>
```

In advance all my appreciation for your help

Comment: It sounds like you probably should be using a templating engine that makes this easy...

Comment: Are you saying that there are hundreds of files like this, and you need to edit them all in a similar way? Why not change the generator, and regenerate them?

Comment: Don't know a lot about templating engines, but don't see how they would work.

Comment: Sorry Tom Lord, I do not understand... Generator?!!
Yes, do have loads of files all completely different, except the snippet of a title code that exists on all, but also never the same.
I thought (redux) being the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading/using Visual Studio Code Community and doing a find and replace in multiple files

[Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346481/how-do-i-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code) to someone else who has done this.