# How can I convert named imports to default imports in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode and trying to correct the way imports are written across multiple files in my project to a more performant format - does VSCode have functionality that would facilitate this? Could it be done with the built-in find and replace? Or is some other VSCode feature able to do this?

The imports I've got look like this (`substance-ux` is an obfuscated version of a real module name, as I don't want module specific answers):

```js
import { Foo, Bar as BarBar } from '@substance-ux/glyphs';
```

Or maybe:

```js
import {
  GlyphWithLongName as LongName,
  GlyphWithExtraLongName as ExtraLong
} from '@substance-ux/glyphs';
```

And I *need* to convert it into this style, matching imports elsewhere in our project:

```js
import Foo from '@substance-ux/glyphs/Foo';
import BarBar from '@substance-ux/glyphs/Bar';
```

Or this:

```js
import LongName from '@substance-ux/glyphs/GlyphWithLongName';
import ExtraLong from '@substance-ux/glyphs/GlyphWithExtraLongName';
```

(As an aside, the files like `'@substance-ux/glyphs/GlyphWithExtraLongName'` already exist and the docs for the package say that the `@substance-ux/glyphs` module runs a lot of code on import, which slows down development builds.)

Now if I know I have one format or the other, or I know how many then I'm ok to rely on find and replace, e.g. I can use a bit of regex (find: `import \{ (.*), (.*) } from '(@substance-ux/glyphs)';` replace `import $1 from '$3/$1';\nimport $2 from '$3/$2';`) and the [Find and Replace feature in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37346529/1075247).

But if I have variable number of imports, or mixed style (some 'as' some not) I become completely unstuck, if I try to do this in one go.

I know [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_using-textmate-snippets) can do regex capture and some clever replacing using TextMate syntax, but I don't think they can handle variable number of capture groups? Or can they?

Is this possible in VSCode without extensions etc?

Comment: Snippets can handle a variable number of arguments - I have answered a number of SO questions showing that - but I don't think they would work with your format.  I really don't think there is a non-extension or non-script solution to your situation.  I have a pretty neat extension solution if you are interested in that.

Comment: @mark yes, but preferably as an answer so can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Snippets can handle a variable number of arguments - I have answered a number of SO questions showing that - but I don't think they would work with your format where the arguments are already there rather than to be entered as part of the snippet. I really don't think there is a non-extension or non-script solution to your situation.

Using an extension that I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), you can write javascript in a keybinding or a setting.

This keybinding - in your `keybindings.json` - will do what you want (it could also be a setting so that the command would appear in the Command Palette):

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": "(import\\s*{\\s*)([^}]+?)(\\s*}\\s*from\\s*')([^']+)';",
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",
      
        "const from = `$4`;",   // capture group 4 from the find
        
        // using capture group 2 from the find regex
        // note backticks around $2 below because it could contain newlines

        "const splitImports = [...`$2`.matchAll(/(\\w+)(?:$|,)|(\\w+)\\s?as\\s?(\\w+)/g)];",
        
        "let str = '';",
        
        "splitImports.forEach((match, index) => { ",

          // don't add a newline if last match
          "let newline = '';",
          "if (index < splitImports.length - 1) newline = '\\n';",
          
          // note double-escapes necessary
          "if (match[1]) str += `import ${match[1]} from \\'${from}/${match[1]}\\';${newline}`;",
          "if (match[2]) str += `import ${match[3]} from \\'${from}/${match[2]}\\';${newline}`;",
        "}); ",
        
        "return str;",
      
      "}$$"
    ],
    
    "isRegex": true,
    // "restrictFind": "line",
  },
  // "when": "editorLangId == javascript"   // if you want it
}
```

This would work on the entire file as the demo shows.  If you wanted to test it or just have it do the lines you select, enable `"restrictFind": "line"`.

[image: modify imports to a different pattern]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. It's so useful when you use a library like @mui. Worked really good here.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand what the *vscode* program has to do with your code.. The program won't actively change the structure of your code, you will have to do it manually:

**You have this:**

```js
import { Foo, Bar as BarBar } from '@substance-ux/glyphs';
```

**And you want this:**

```js
import Foo from '@substance-ux/glyphs/Foo';
import BarBar from '@substance-ux/glyphs/Bar';
```

The `@substance-ux/glyphs` file is having inside it multiple **named** exports, so
if you want to split things, you will need to create dedicated files which
exports `default`, so create a `Foo.js` file which `export default Foo;` and more all the code from `@substance-ux/glyphs` which is relevant to `Foo` to the new file, or just import from within `Foo.js` and re-expose as the *default*:

#### New `Foo.js` file:

```js
import { Foo } from '@substance-ux/glyphs';
export default Foo;
```

#### New `Bar.js` file:

```js
import { Bar } from '@substance-ux/glyphs';
export default Bar;
```

You can import any *default* exported thing by any name you wish:

```js
import Banana from '@substance-ux/glyphs/Bar';
```

But I don't see why would you want to do this.. You didn't explain to us what is bad with importing multiple things from a single file. Treeshaking?